# Elasticsearch Exception : es_rejected_execution_exception

Tags: elasticsearch

Getting error while ingesting data into elasticsearch.

```
{
"error": {
    "root_cause": [
        {
            "type": "remote_transport_exception",
            "reason": "[10.23.10.165][10.23.10.165:9300][indices:data/write/bulk[s][p]]"
        }
    ],
    "type": "es_rejected_execution_exception",
    "reason": "rejected execution of processing of [249060237][indices:data/write/bulk[s][p]]: request: BulkShardRequest [[19-01-2022_content_vod][0]] containing [index {[content_vod][_doc][2581344], source[n/a, actual length: [3kb], max length: 2kb]}], target allocation id: 7kXMhnrkREmTkY5X9Dr8LQ, primary term: 8 on EsThreadPoolExecutor[name = 10.23.10.165/write, queue capacity = 5000, org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsThreadPoolExecutor@6b7dd2e7[Running, pool size = 4, active threads = 4, queued tasks = 5000, completed tasks = 11276660]]"
},
"status": 429
```

}

**My Settings are default settings**,to address this issues what all elasticsearch settings should be changed.

**Please advise** what should be ideal thread pool settings.

My Elasticsearch is running on C5.8xLarge machine and has 4 nodes.

Answer (score 0):

When the [search/write queue/threadpool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-threadpool.html) is full Elasticsearch will throw `es_rejected_execution_exception`. If you have a retry mechanism for indexing (eg. a message queue like Kafka or RabbitMQ) there won't be any issue and the application you used for indexing will retry the indexing. If you don't have any retry mechanism it can cause **data loss**.

The current `queue capacity` from the log you shared is 5k and it's filled because of the high indexing rate.

### Increasing the write queue capacity will only delay `es_rejected_execution_exception`. To fix this problem you can check this article.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-indexing-speed.html

To find the root cause and monitor your cluster you can use the [Opster AutoOps](https://opster.com/elasticsearch-autoops/).